# Error: Cyclic dependency after updating nuxt to v2.3.4

Tags: nuxt.js, webpack-4

Stuck at after chunk asset optimization (93%)

Showing error like this
/node_modules/toposort/index.js:35
throw new Error('Cyclic dependency' + nodeRep)

I am getting this error continuously. To update my app I follow the steps carefully but still, nothing comes out.
Please look into it.

```
      throw new Error('Cyclic dependency' + nodeRep)
      ^

Error: Cyclic dependency
    at visit (/var/www/html/app/node_modules/toposort/index.js:35:13)
    at visit (/var/www/html/app/node_modules/toposort/index.js:53:9)
    at visit (/var/www/html/app/node_modules/toposort/index.js:53:9)
    at visit (/var/www/htmlapp/node_modules/toposort/index.js:53:9)
    at Function.toposort [as array] (/var/www/html/app/node_modules/toposort/index.js:22:22)
    at Object.module.exports.dependency (/var/www/html/app/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/chunksorter.js:50:35)
    at HtmlWebpackPlugin.sortChunks (/var/www/html/app/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/index.js:364:35)

...
```

Comment: its impossible to tell what wrogn without actual code of app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error when I tried to Lazy Loading multiples Child Components in a Component.

#### Cause of the issue

The issue is caused by a library called [toposort](https://www.npmjs.com/package/toposort) which is used by `html-webpack-plugin` on versions < 4.0.0 ([it was removed](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/981#issuecomment-399345841)).

Nuxt updated the `html-webpack-plugin` to v4 in the [v2.13](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/7489).

#### Solutions

#### Solution 1

Update Nuxt to version  [v2.13](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/7489) or a newer one.

#### Solution 2

If you can't update Nuxt to [v2.13](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/7489) or a newer one, you can apply the following solution in the `nuxt.config.js`

**nuxt.config.js**

```
const htmlPlugin = config.plugins.find(_ => _.constructor.name === 'HtmlWebpackPlugin')
if (htmlPlugin) {
  Object.assign(htmlPlugin.options, { chunksSortMode: 'none' })
}
```

I got that solution from the following issues reported in the `nuxt` and `vue-cli` repositories:

- https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1669#issuecomment-446595864
- https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/3951#issuecomment-424871594

Also, it was the solution applied in `vue-cli`:

- https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/commit/744c375fba8b2055706f38b524a83fd5ea845686